# How to set ATOM text editor setting find and replace to CASE SENSITIVE

Tags: atom-editor

I'm new to Atom and trying to find a way to set the options find and replace to "case sensitive" insated of "case insensitive" as default .

Where to change it in setting ? does it have to do with project-find-view-spec.js ? if so, can you guide me to specific location ? I don't know coffee.. Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a simple config option.

Go to `ATOM`/`Open Your Config` and add the following lines;

```
  'find-and-replace':
    'caseSensitive': true
```

(2 spaces before the first line, 4 before the second, putting it nested inside `global`)

Restart Atom and the default should be case sensitive.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for regex searches? I can't seem to add `/ /c` options to the regex search.